# ADFS as OAuth2 provider / Authentication server possible?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, adfs, adfs3.0

We want to setup ADFS 3.0 to enable OAuth2 based authentication.  I have read lots of documentation, but am still unclear if this is supported.

Can ADFS be used as an authorization server for oauth, or is oauth2 support in ADFS only meant to work as a client to another authorization server?

Any help for setting up adfs as oauth provider/server is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in ADFS 2012R2 (aka ADFS 3.0), we only support the authorization grant flow. The only scenario is for public clients (say a mobile app on iOS/Android/Windows) to access a RESTful service and authorizing via JWT tokens. You can see this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx

With ADFS 2016 (which will release imminently), you have the full Oauth/OIDC support. With this you can build web apps, single page apps, API's, multi-tiered app systems that require On-behalf-of support, confidential clients (with support for windows service accounts acting as confidential clients). You can check this out https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development